# non-destructive filter in OpenGL

Tags: ios, graphics, opengl-es, filter

I am making a photography app for the iPhone and will be using OpenGL to apply effects to the images. Now I'm a bit of an OpenGL noob and was wondering is there a way to build a filter(saturation & blur) that can be easily reversed?

To explain, the user takes a picture and then applies a blur of 5 and a saturation of 3(arbitrary values), but then comes back and turns it down to a blur of 3 and a saturation of 2, would the result be same as if he had given the original image a blur of 3 and a saturation of 2?

Answer (score 0):

Save the original image and store the filter changes as an array of instructions that you can replay at a later date.  This will also give you selective undo ability.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot redo filters like blur. Such filters looses some of information about the image so it is hard to get it back. See [discussion here](http://www.blitzbasic.com/Community/posts.php?topic=88859).

Using OpenGL (or any other Api) you can easily apply filter as "postprocessing" effects. Just render a quad with your texture to some render target and then you will have transformed image as an output.
Here is a [link to oZone3D](http://www.ozone3d.net/tutorials/image_filtering.php) how to do that.

You can save the created output (but as some other filename!).

Answer (score 0):

Non-destructive editing is API agnostic, you can implement it with OpenGL or in software or anything, all you really need to do is keep aside the source data instead of overwriting it. You can even push back "history" to disk to avoid bloating the ram and gpu memory.

From the context of your question I can assume you are using some of the out-of-the-box ready-to-use functions apple provides for their API, it this case you rely on a stock implementation, so you are stuck with its destructive behavior until you come up with something better yourself.